# Confusion with intersection multiplicities of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading Gathmann's notes on plane algebraic curves and I have a presumably very simple confusion with the intersection multiplicities.  Let $F,G \in K[x,y]$ for some field $K$ and define the intersection multiplicity of $F$ and $G$ at a point $P \in \mathbb{A}^2_K$, denoted $\mu_p(F,G)$, as the dimension over $K$ of the vector space $\mathcal{O}_p / \langle F,G\rangle$, where $\mathcal{O}_p$ is the ring of rational functions with coefficients in $K$ and with denominator not vanishing at $p$.

I thought I understood this, and even followed some calculations, but now I am realizing that I am confused.  The curves $x$ and $y$ have intersection multiplicity 1 at $p = (0,0)$.  So in this case I imagine $\mathcal{O}_p / \langle F,G\rangle$ consists just of the constant functions.  But then how do I express say $\frac{1}{1+x}$ or $\frac{3}{3x^2 + xy^2+4}$ as a constant function in $\mathcal{O}_p / \langle x,y\rangle$?

I imagine my confusion can be cleared up with just a simple comment and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If $x=y=0$, what does $\frac{1}{1+x}$ equal? Please also use \langle and \rangle instead of < and > - I've fixed this for you this time with an edit.

Comment: @KReiser I see, the evaluation map is an isomorphism to $K$.  Thanks - I'll do that in the future.  I guess, I'm still wondering how to then write $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 + \frac{a}{b}x + \frac{c}{d}y$.

Comment: Oh sorry - I see it now: $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 + \frac{-1-y}{1+x} x+ \frac{x}{1+x}y$, for example.  Thanks for the help!